# How to differentiate between a number and a letter or sign?

Tags: python, string, function, integer

If I have a digit within a string I can just do:

```
x = "2"
x.isdigit()
```

and I get True. But when I do this:

```
isinstance(x, str)
```

By my understanding this also results in True.

My question is now how can I tell if it is a character or a number?

Comment: All 'numbers', eg: `"2"` or `"9"` are characters, but most characters, eg: `"a"` or `"j"` are not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isalpha()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/isalpha.html) for this:

```
x = "2"
x.isalpha()
```

Returns `False`

Comment: if it is only '-' you can check for equality with `x == '-'`, which returns `True` for `-`

Answer (score 0):

The isdigit number checks every character in string and checks if its a digit or not, in other words, can be an number or not, it returns true if every digit is integer.
while the isinstance primarily checks the datatype of the value you pass.

```
x='2'
isinstance(x,integer)
```

Since x itself is a string, isinstance(x,str) returns true.
So, to find whether a string contains a number or character, just use x.isdigit(), it will always return true if its a digit otherwise false.